# Issue with Boost Library Queues

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use queues from boost library.

When my queue definitions are as below, the compilation passes and everything works as expected.

```
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue1(128);
boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue2(128);
```

However when I change my code as shown below (i.e wrap the queue inside a structure), the compilation fails with the below errors.

```
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct stack { 
  int top;
  boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue1(128);
  boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue2(128);
} stack;


~/prgms$ g++ two_queue_to_stack.cpp 
two_queue_to_stack.cpp:9:38: error: expected identifier before numeric constant 
boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue1(128);
                                  ^
two_queue_to_stack.cpp:9:38: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant 
two_queue_to_stack.cpp:10:38: error: expected identifier before numeric constant 
boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue2(128);
                                  ^
two_queue_to_stack.cpp:10:38: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

Whats wrong with the above definitions ? Am i missing some thing basic here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
struct stack { 
  int top;
  boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue1, queue2;

  // initialize the member objects, queue1, queue2, during construction of stack
  stack() : queue1(128), queue2(128) {
  }
```